# Cannot Get item form dynamodb using aws proxy in aws api gateway?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

i am working with dynamodb to insert and retrieve records from dynamo. please note that when i insert the record to dynamo db it is working fine but when i try to list any item or retrieve any item from dynamodb  it return **no result found**

for retrieving of record

1. created a iam role which has trust relationship with api gateway. and has managed policies : AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess , AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess , APIGatewayAWSProxyExecPolicy , AmazonAPIGatewayAdministrator.
2. created a table named, emp which has the field ID and name.
3. created an api gateway named emp, which has resource /employee. and has method post and get. post for insert and get for display record.
4. for get method selected aws service proxy 
   [image]
5. then in URL Query String Parameters added id in method request.
6. then also in integration request > URL Query String Parameters added > ID and method.request.querystring.id.
7. in integration request > body mapping template added application/json and then the json code

   {
       "TableName": "emp",
       "KeyConditionExpression": "ID = :v1",
       "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
           ":v1": {
               "S": "$input.params('ID')"
           }
       }
   }
   then when i tested it it returns no result I cannot figure out why please help.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample data present in the 'emp' table ?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not an expert on this, but I can see two issues.

First in the DynamoDB service proxy settings the HTTP method needs to be POST, as you are POSTing a request to DynamoDB API, and it has nothing to do with the the fact the you use the GetItem method.

Second, your body mapping template uses KeyconditionExpression that is used in DynamoDB Query API, but not in the GetItem. GetItem needs a Key specified, like here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html#API_GetItem_Examples

Hope this helps.